# Why BelongsTo() isn't working in Laravel 6?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I've got two Models `User` and `AccountType`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    (...)

    public function accountType()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\AccountType', 'account_type_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

```
class AccountType extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'account_types';
  // protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  public function users()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\User');
  }
}
```

My database:

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('account_type_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('account_type_id')->references('id')->on('account_types');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

```
        Schema::create('account_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('account_type_name');
        });
```

When I use hasMany - everything works like a charm, but when I try to use `$user->accountType->account_type_name` it doesn't work. Loop that I use to print my users:

```
                @foreach ($users as $user)
                  <tr>
                    <td>{{ $user->full_name }}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#" class="badge badge-pill badge-warning">No team</a>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      xyz
                    </td>
                    <td> {{ $user->accountType->account_type_name }} </td>
                    <td><a href="mailto:{{ $user->email }}">{{ $user->email }}</a></td>
                    <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
                  </tr>
                @endforeach
```

And the error. When I comment out  `$user->accountType->account_type_name` it works fine.

```
ErrorException
Undefined offset: 1
```

Details here - https://flareapp.io/share/jKPgOZPa

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @DilipHirapara I've added those to my question. Sorry :)

Comment: Do all users have account type id in the users table?

Comment: Yes, they are getting it by default.

Comment: I'm not saying that's a mistake but can you change and check it if 1) `accountType()` name should be in small `'account_type()'` 2) In AccountType model `return $this->hasMany('App\User','account_type_id', 'id');`

Comment: your error and the reason behind it seems unusual. you should get an error like `trying to get properties of non object`. you can eager load your data and dd in controller to check what is actually going on.

Comment: Thing is that I get `null` from `$user->accountType->account_type_name` so there's definitely something wrong with this relation.

Comment: use `{{ $user->account_type_id }}` and check if you get the raw id.

Comment: Yep, I do get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've replaced `<td> {{ $user->accountType->account_type_name }} </td>` with `<td> {{ App\User::find($user->id)->accountType->account_type_name }} </td>`, now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: Do yo mean you tried to get record in a template file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use snake case instead of camel case:

```
<td> {{ $user->account_type->account_type_name }} </td>
```

Comment: Didn't really help. Tried to use snake case in blade.php only as well in both model and blade.php

Comment: It seems may be some user didn't have valid account type try this: `<td> {{ $user->account_type->account_type_name ?? '' }} </td>` and see if any user came up with empty account type

Comment: This is exactly what I have right now. The thing is that I have two users, each of them has valid `user_type_id`

Comment: What `user_type_id`  is valid but you are making relation on `account_type_id` in User Model???

Comment: A typo here; of course you're right, I meant `account_type_id`

Comment: I see your error details its not coming from account type. You are not rendering your view correctly in your controller. You need to pass data array correctly to your view string.

Comment: `return view('users')->with('users', User::paginate(50));` this is what I do. And once again, everything works fine and the users are printed in the table if I comment out `$user->account_type->account_type_name`

Comment: Then it should work with this `<td> {{ $user->account_type->account_type_name ?? '' }} </td>` and Are you using Soft Deletes?

Comment: It does not.. When it comes to your question about soft deletes - not yet.

Comment: Thanks. When ever you solve this please let me know what was causing this issue. its really weird.

Comment: It could only be the case if you are not selecting `account_type_id` in your first query. like `User::select('id',name)->get()` but this shouldn't be the case with `return view('users')->with('users', User::paginate(50)); `. any way congrats

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have wrong relationship defined. Your User model should be like:

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    (...)

    public function accountType()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\AccountType', 'account_type_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

and Account type model should be like:

```
class AccountType extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'account_types';
    // protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function user()
    {
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Comment: This way we have one-to-one relationship, and I wart to achieve thing that one account_type can have multiple users, and one user only one account_type.

Comment: To make it work `$user->accountType->account_type_name`  you will need to define a relation like I mentioned.

Comment: I can't see why; ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse

Comment: The definition `accountType` in User model is wrong. Doing this the model will try to find a record in `account_types` table by `account_type_id`. While he is having `account_type_id` field in `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.... Mine is working perfectly..

```
$user->accountType->first() ->account_type_name
```